# Grammar in terms of referring to the future

Tags: grammar, future-tense

Keeping it short. In terms of the future tense, is the grammar of the following sentence correct?

"Nobody would continue this tradition."

Comment: Your sentence is conditional, even though it comments on the future. Future tense is "Nobody will continue this tradition." In English, future tense is generally verb in present tense plus "will." Maybe clarify your question to say whether you mean to refer to the future of actually use future tense of a particular verb. English is gnerally not like Spanish or other languages that conjugate a future tense.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'll rephrase the question to clarify but the sentence is meant to refer to the future.

Comment: I think your question is OK, but since you used "could," I wasn't sure you actually had to use future tense.

Comment: I thought I used would.

Comment: My mistake! "Would" is of course what you wrote, and that makes it conditional, although many grammar references say that conditional also requires an "if" clause.

Comment: If your sentence were part of a past narrative it might refer to the future with respect to the moment of narration.

Comment: @Ant_222 Not the case. Some grammar guides refer to the "probability" factor in terms of the usage of would. For example, "would" may be used to express that the action is not definite. Is there such a rule?

Comment: @hbr Yes, but that rule belongs to the subject of the conditional, which your example is not.

Comment: This looks correct. People have to realize, especially English language learners, that spoken and written English do not always follow the specific rules of a text. Part of learning or using any language properly is being absorbed in it, using it with native speakers, learning what is accepted and what is not, etc... That sentence is correct. Also, what @Ant_222 said is correct as well. It could be used to narrate something in the past which was about the future. But the sentence is correct with respect to conveying the idea of no one continuing a certain tradition in the future.